# Check local time in if-statement

Tags: android

I managed to get the local time, but now I want to use it in an if statement like this:

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
  Date currentLocalTime = cal.getTime();
  DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
  // you can get seconds by adding  "...:ss" to it
  date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+1:00"));
  String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

  Log.w(localTime, "1");

  if (localTime == "12:11") {
     Log.w("Yes", "this is");
  }
  else {
     Log.w("jhlgsaljfd", "kajfhsd");
  }
```

However, this is not working, how to check the local time in the if-else statement?

Comment: What value you get in the "localTime" ?.You get correct time in this variable? show your logcat..

Comment: By the way you do not know how use Log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `equals` instead `==`, It should be:

```
if (localTime.equals("12:11")){
    Log.w("Yes", "this is");
}
else {
    Log.w("jhlgsaljfd", "kajfhsd");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do string comparison using `==`  u need to use like this

```
if("12:11".equals(localTime ))
```

You can use this too

```
if (localTime.equals("12:11"))
```

But sometime this may cause NullPointerException.(When ur string is null or not initailized)